# Remove and obtain the value of select tags appearing after a changed select tag

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a below set of select tags

```
<div class="select_tags">
<select>
<option>val1</option>
<option>val2</option>
</select>
<select>
<option>val11</option>
<option>val12</option>
</select>
<select>
<option>val21</option>
<option>val22</option>
</select>
</div>
```

```
$(document).on('change', '.select_tags select', function() {
 
    }
```

If the select tag value is already been changed and if the user tries to select the options (or change the options) again I want to remove the select tags appearing after the selected select tag

For ex if the user selects the first set of select tag which they had already changed and selected the option value the div tag should contain only the changed set of tag and remove the tags appearing after it and get the selected option values for the tags that are removed

Result required

```
<div class="select_tags">
<select>
<option>val1</option>
<option>val2</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something using `.nextAll()`:

```
$(document).on('change', '.select_tags select', function() {
  $(this).nextAll("select").remove();
});
```

Snippet here:

```js
$(function () {
  $(document).on('change', '.select_tags select', function () {
    console.log([...$(this).nextAll("select").map(function () {
      return $(this).val();
    })]);
    $(this).nextAll("select").remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="select_tags">
  <select>
    <option>val1</option>
    <option>val2</option>
  </select>
  <select>
    <option>val11</option>
    <option>val12</option>
  </select>
  <select>
    <option>val21</option>
    <option>val22</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thankyou..there was one more question added how to get the removed select tags choosed options?

Comment: Any updation please?

Comment: @shee8 Sorry, I didn't notice. I didn't understand. Let me read the question again.

Comment: @shee8 Updated, check the console.